# Questions about the documentation of the Kafka Protocol

Tags: apache-kafka

I implement the Kafka protocol for the Dart language. My implementation is based on the documentation at [Kafka Protocol Guide](https://kafka.apache.org/protocol).

I have 2 questions to that:

1.) There are 3 versions of the request header and 2 versions of the response header. Beside that, the requests and responses are also available in multiple versions. What is not documented from my point of view is which version of request uses which version of the request header (same for response and response header). Where is this information documented?

2.) The documentation references the [KIP-482](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-482%3A+The+Kafka+Protocol+should+Support+Optional+Tagged+Fields). Is the KIP implemented as documented or were there changes made while it was implemented?

Answer (score 2):

After der discussion with [OneCricketeer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/onecricketeer) I looked into the sources of the Java client. There I found the file [ApiMessageTypeGenerator.java](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/3.4.0/generator/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/message/ApiMessageTypeGenerator.java#L324) (version 3.4.0).

The code there is used to generate the source of another class with the logic to determine the header version of a request/response.

For the requests it looks like that every request that supports flexible versions uses a header of version 2 and all other a header of version 1.

For the responses it is header version 1 for responses supporting flexible versions and otherwise header version 0.

Additionally, there are 2 hardcoded exceptions in the linked source:

- `ApiVersionsResponse` [always includes a v0 header](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/3.4.0/generator/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/message/ApiMessageTypeGenerator.java#L336)
- `ControlledShutdownRequest` [has a non-standard header](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/3.4.0/generator/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/message/ApiMessageTypeGenerator.java#L343)

The generator works on files like [ProduceRequest.json](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/resources/common/message/ProduceRequest.json).